How to place the text at the upper-left corner of the rectangle
How can I place the text Register at the upper-left corner of the rectangle?
I used \pgfpoint{15pt}{-5pt} to demonstrate the desired visual effect.
But I want to calculate the width, height, and depth of the text Register, so I can place the text more accurately and elegantly.
Then I read How can the dimensions of a box be retrieved with LaTeX, and produced the following code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/width/.initial=2cm,
    /tikz/height/.initial=1cm,
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{register}{
    \savedmacro\operatorparameters{
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\register@width}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/width}}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\register@height}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/height}}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\register@halfwidth}{.5*\register@width}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\register@halfheight}{.5*\register@height}
        \pgf@xa=\register@halfwidth\relax
        \pgf@ya=\register@halfheight\relax
    }
    \savedanchor{\center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{center}{\center}
    \savedanchor{\north}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@ya}}
    \savedanchor{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \savedanchor{\northwest}{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \savedanchor{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \savedanchor{\southeast}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \anchor{n}{\north}
    \anchor{ne}{\northeast}
    \anchor{se}{\southeast}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\southwest}
        \pgfpathlineto{\northwest}
        \pgfpathlineto{\northeast}
        \pgfpathlineto{\southeast}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgfusepath{stroke}

        \def\register@name{\tiny Register}
        \newsavebox{\register@name@box}
        \sbox{\register@name@box}{\register@name}

        \bgroup
        \pgftransformshift{
            \pgfpointadd{
                \pgfpoint{-\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}
            }{
                \pgfpoint{15pt}{-5pt} % <------------------------
                %\pgfpoint{.5*\the\wd\register@name@box}{-.5*(\the\ht\register@name@box+\the\dp\register@name@box)}
            }
        }
        \pgftext{\register@name}
        \egroup

        \bgroup
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1cm}}
        \pgftext{the depth=\the\dp\register@name@box}
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1cm}}
        \pgftext{the height=\the\ht\register@name@box}
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1cm}}
        \pgftext{the width=\the\wd\register@name@box}
        \egroup
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw(0,0)node[register,width=8cm](multiplicand){};
        \fill(0,0)circle(2pt);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Alas, I got the width, height, and depth of the text are 0pt!
I don't know what to do next.
The following is the console output:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> pre-release-0 (develop 2022-6-17 branch)
L3 programming layer <2022-06-02>
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/circuitikz/circuitikz.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
meta.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarybending.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulebending.co
de.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulenonlineart
ransformations.code.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarycurvili
near.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryfpu.code.tex
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.cod
e.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirc.defines.tex)
 (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircutils.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircpath.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircshapes.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircmonopoles.tex
) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircbipoles.tex
)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirctripoles.tex)

(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircquadpoles.tex
)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircmultipoles.te
x) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirclabel.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircvoltage.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirccurrent.tex)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircflow.tex))
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
[1{/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )</texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb></texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr5.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 24196 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on test.log.


Inside the tikzpicture, the default font is the null font, so text has no dimensions. This is switched inside nodes, for example.
